# How to resample a .wav sound file which is being read using the wavfile.read?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy, librosa

I want to change the following two lines of my code:

```
clip, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_name)
clip = librosa.resample(clip, sample_rate, 2000)
```

I want to load the `.wav` file using `wavfile.read()` instead of using `librosa.load()` and then resample it using some technique other than the `libroa.resample()`.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is the answer folks! The below solution worked for me.

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
import scipy.signal as sps
from io import BytesIO

new_rate = 2000
# Read file
sample_rate, clip = wavfile.read(BytesIO(file_name))
       
# Resample data
number_of_samples = round(len(clip) * float(new_rate) / sample_rate)
clip = sps.resample(clip, number_of_samples)
```